# Strange error involving "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' "

Tags: python, attributeerror

so i am trying to parse out a text file by converting it to a list and splitting each item in the list at the space.

i have created a test variable to run this part of the code by itself.
my code in the spyder editor:

```
test = ['NC_009142.1_03_012_002_001 560', 'NC_017586.1_13_009_003_001 555', 'NC_016111.1_13_010_003_001 555']
ListOfLinesParsed = test

PN_List = []
counter_iterative = 0
while counter_iterative < len(ListOfLinesParsed):
    PN_List = PN_List.append(ListOfLinesParsed[counter_iterative].split()[0])
    counter_iterative += 1

print PN_List
```

Which returns an error:

> > > runfile(r'/home/jake/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir=r'/home/jake/.spyder2')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 493, in runfile

    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/jake/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 7, in <module>

    PN_List = PN_List.append(ListOfLinesParsed[counter_iterative].split()[0])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

BUT if i enter the commands directly into the terminal i get no error:

> > > testL = []
> > >
> > > testL.append(test[0].split()[0])
> > >
> > > testL

```
['NC_009142.1_03_012_002_001']
```

> > > testL.append(test[1].split()[0])
> > >
> > > testL

```
['NC_009142.1_03_012_002_001', 'NC_017586.1_13_009_003_001']
```

> > > testL.append(test[2].split()[0])
> > >
> > > testL

```
['NC_009142.1_03_012_002_001', 'NC_017586.1_13_009_003_001', 'NC_016111.1_13_010_003_001']
```

Shouldn't the 2 things be EXACTLY the same? i don't understand why the one in my script is acting any differently than the terminal commands.

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
PN_List = PN_List.append(ListOfLinesParsed[counter_iterative].split()[0])
```

is the problem.

`list.append` is an *in-place* operation, which returns `None`, but alters the original list itself. If you assign `PN_List` to the result, it becomes `None`. If you don't, then your program will run smoothly. This is why when you try appending things without an assignment, you get the expected answer.

Comment: thank you. the moment you quoted the line i face-palmed but sometimes it's too obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
PN_List = PN_List.append(ListOfLinesParsed[counter_iterative].split()[0])
```

is the issue here. Since `.append()` returns `None` and you have saved your list to this `NoneType` value, on the second iteration, you will get an error because you are trying to use a `.append()` on a `NoneType`. This is also why you don't get an error in the console because the problem only occurrs the second time you use the above line.

So instead, simply do:

```
PN_List.append(ListOfLinesParsed[counter_iterative].split()[0])
```